# Removing UIView' backing layer from superLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer

```
-(void) testLayer {

    UIView *parent = [UIView new];
    UIView *subview1 = [UIView new];
    UIView *subview2 = [UIView new];

    [parent addSubview:subview1];
    [parent addSubview:subview2];

    XCTAssertTrue(subview1.superview != nil);

    XCTAssertTrue([parent.subviews count] == 2);

    [subview1.layer removeFromSuperlayer];

    XCTAssertTrue(subview1.superview == nil);


    XCTAssertTrue([parent.subviews count] == 1); //This test case failing

}
```

Can someone explain why the last test case is failing? I must be missing something basic here.

I know that `[subview1 removeFromSuperview]` is the right way to remove it from the superView but I am interested in knowing what is happening here behind the scenes.

My confusion is because `subview1.superview` is nil after executing `[subview1.layer removeFromSuperlayer]` but the subviews array still has both subviews in it.

Comment: If you want to remove a subview, you do `[subview1 removeFromSuperview]`. Removing a subview’s backing layer is not the same thing as removing the subview, itself.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is so obvious:
`[subview1.layer removeFromSuperlayer]` removes a layer whereas in `parent.subviews` you're calling for 'views'. Since a view and layer are different, the test case fails.
As Apple says about removeFromSuperlayer:

> You can use this method to remove a layer (and all of its sublayers)
>   from a layer hierarchy. This method updates both the superlayer’s list
>   of sublayers and **sets this layer’s superlayer property to nil**

.